# How to create Facebook page with like button, if user like the page I will show him the content

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I need to create Page with like button, if the user click on the like button I will show him the page content else he will still see the landing page until he click like?

Thanks for help.

Regards,

Eco

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can use

```
<?php
$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);

$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

$app_data = isset($data["app_data"]) ? $data["app_data"] : '';
$_REQUEST["fb_page_id"] = $data["page"]["id"];
$access_admin = $data["page"]["admin"] == 1;
$has_liked = $data["page"]["liked"] == 1;
?>
```

and you can check if like using $has_liked

```
<?php if($has_liked) : ?>
fan-specifc
<?php else : ?>
for non-fans only
<?php endif; ?>
```